# Hide and Show Markers in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

i need a help. I'm not good at JS right now, can you give me solution?
I need to remove this marker, by using checkbox or button. I'm trying finding the solution on internet, but i still don't get it. I hope you can help me guys, thank you so much.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//MARKER DATA FROM DB
var locations = [@foreach($kegiatan as $kegiatan)['{{$kegiatan->tanggal}}',{{$kegiatan->lat}},{{$kegiatan->lng}},'{{$kegiatan->gambar}}','{{$kegiatan->nama_tatanan}}','{{$kegiatan->nama_program}}','{{$kegiatan->pelaksanaan}}','{{$kegiatan->nama_kecamatan}}','{{$kegiatan->nama_kelurahan}}','{{$kegiatan->nama_kegiatan}}','{{$kegiatan->nama_indikator}}'],@endforeach];

function initialize() {
  //PUT THE MAP INTO DIV
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
  //INIT MAP
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.390487,106.818807),
  zoom: 13,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

//GIVE LAYER
  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
      select: "col17",
      from: "1kKFhr-EJ8uWfHlnV3o6Iqzdu-NGosuZr30Phs3HW",
      where: ""
  },
  options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
  }
  });

  //MAKE VAR MARKER, URL
  var marker, i, infowindow;
  var assetUrl = '{{asset("img/kegiatan/")}}'

  function setMapOnAll(){
    for(i=0; i<locations.length; i++){
  //CREATE MARKER
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: "{{asset('img/marker/marker.png')}}",
  });

  //CREATE INFOWINDOW
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  //CLICK FUNCTION FOR INFOWINDOW
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent('<div class="infowindow">'+ '<b> ' + locations[i][9] + '</b>' + '<p>' + locations[i][0] + '</p>' + '<img src="' + assetUrl + '/' + locations[i][3] + '">' + '<br><br><div><b>Nama Tatanan : </b>' + locations[i][4] + '</div><br><div><b>Nama Indikator : </b>' + locations[i][10] +  '</div><br><div><b>Nama Program : </b>'+ locations[i][5] + '<br><br><div><b>Nama Pelaksana : </b>'+ locations[i][6] + '</div><br><div><b>Nama Kecamatan : </b>'+locations[i][7]+'</div><br><div><b>Nama Kelurahan : </b>'+locations[i][8]+'</div></div>');
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
  }
  setMapOnAll();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

The resulit will be like this

[What it is looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqksF.png)

Comment: It's not clear from your question what marker you are trying to remove.  Can you clarify where the checkbox or button are, and identify which marker you are trying to remove?

Comment: @Daniel im trying to remove the marker, for me its up to you if u wanna use checkbox or button :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't understood of your comment but you can use this javascript for maps:

`let map;
    map = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.0059413),
        zoom: 13,
        styles: [
            {
                "featureType":"water",
                "elementType":"geometry",
                "stylers":[{"color":"#e9e9e9"},{"lightness":17}]},
            {
                "featureType":"landscape",
                "elementType":"geometry",
                "stylers":[
                    {"color":"#f5f5f5"},
                    {"lightness":20}]},
            {
                "featureType":"road.highway",
                "elementType":"geometry.fill",
                "stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},
                    {"lightness":17}]},
            {"featureType":"road.highway",
                "elementType":"geometry.stroke",
                "stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},
                    {"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},
            {"featureType":"road.arterial",
                "elementType":"geometry",
                "stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},
                    {"lightness":18}]},
            {"featureType":"road.local",
                "elementType":"geometry",
                "stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},
                    {"lightness":16}]},
            {"featureType":"poi",
                "elementType":"geometry",
                "stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},
                    {"lightness":21}]},
            {"featureType":"poi.park",
                "elementType":"geometry",
                "stylers":[{"color":"#dedede"},
                    {"lightness":21}]},     {"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},     {"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#333333"},{"lightness":40}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]}]
    });
    let map_icon = 'assets/images/map-marker.png';
    map.addMarker({
        position: {lat: 40.7127837, lng: -74.0059413},
        lat: 40.7127837,
        lng: -74.0059413,
        title: 'New York',
        icon: map_icon,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
        details: {
            database_id: 42,
            author: 'HPNeo'
        },
        click: function(e){
            if(console.log)
                console.log(e);
            alert('You clicked in this marker');
        },
        mouseover: function(e){
            if(console.log)
                console.log(e);
        }
    });
 </pre>`

I hope it helps